# JSON Sharepoint Calculated Columns

Tags: column, json, conditional

First time coding with JSON and need a little help...... I am attempting to make a calculated column with conditional formatting. So far i can get it to work but only partially. What i want is to have all cells default to green when empty (basic code), but change color based on the value.....

Basic Code Works

```
{
    "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
    "elmType": "div",
    "style": {
        "color": "#ffffff",
        "padding-left": "10px",
        "background-color": "#0000ff"
    },
    "children": [{
            "elmType": "span",
            "txtContent": "$ ",
            "style": {
                "display": "inline-block",
                "padding": "0 1px"
            }
        },
        {
            "elmType": "span",
            "txtContent": "[$cSDP_x0020_Hardware_x0020_Varian]",
            "attributes": {
                "class": ""
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

[image: text]

But when i add an if statement the conditions work but the empty cells do not turn green.....

```
{
    "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
    "elmType": "div",
    "style": {
        "color": "#000000",
        "padding-left": "10px",
            "background-color": "= if(@currentField < 0 ,'#CB4335',  if(@currentField < ([$cSDP_x0020_Hardware_x0020_Budget] * 0.15) ,'#FFC7CE', if(@currentField < ([$cSDP_x0020_Hardware_x0020_Budget] * 0.3),'#FFEB9C', '#dff6dd'))"
    },


    "children": [{
            "elmType": "span",
            "txtContent": "$ ",
            "style": {
                "display": "inline-block",
                "padding": "0 1px"
            }
        },
        {
            "elmType": "span",
            "style": {
                "overflow": "hidden",
                "text-overflow": "ellipsis",
                "padding": "0 3px"
            },
            "txtContent": "[$cSDP_x0020_Hardware_x0020_Varian]",
            "attributes": {
                "class": ""
            }

        }
    ]

}
```

[image: text]

The column/field the formula is evaluating is a calculated number field and I am wondering if that has anything to do with it? I have played around with simple calculations as well and can not seem to even evaluate a value as "0", null, or '' in the if statement.

I have been at this for a few days trying different ways to get it to work and feel i must be missing something simple in the code? I really hope this isn't a stupid SharePoint limitation situation.....

Thanks for your help!

Screenshot #3
[image: text]

Comment: What is the formula for [..Variance]? Based on the data, it looks like [Budget-Actual]. The calculated field, [variance], is going to have a value of 0, >0 or <0. Do you mean why value of 0 doesn't have a green background? For that, You need to add one more condition  "=if(@currentField==0, 'green', if(@currentField < 0 ,'#CB4335', ..)))".

Comment: Thanks - Yes i want to highglight when the project costs are at certain thresholds of the budget, ie more than 30% remaining in budget, under 30% of budget remaining, under 15% of the budget, 0, over spent. As for the code, its the values below the 5th row that are not rendering that evaluate to 0 without JSON that are not rendering. They only render when data is added to the hardware budget and actual fields even if its a zero?

Comment: Try adding this additional condition in your existing condition : `if((@currentField == 0) || (@currentField == ''),'#dff6dd', <other conditions here>`. These conditions are totally based on what value you are returning using your calculated formulas. So, change conditions accordingly. Let me know if this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the current IF condition in the `Background` attribute with the below one:

```
=  if((@currentField == 0) || (@currentField.length == 0),'#dff6dd',if(@currentField < 0 ,'#CB4335',if((@currentField <= ([$cSDP_x0020_Hardware_x0020_Budget] * 0.15)) && (@currentField > 0),'#FFC7CE',if((@currentField <= ([$cSDP_x0020_Hardware_x0020_Budget] * 0.3)) && (@currentField > 0),'#FFEB9C',''))))
```

**Output**

As you can see, the empty cell has been highlighted with white green background as you need!

[image]

> Check also, **[JSON SharePoint Date Column Formatting in SharePoint 2019 and SharePoint Online](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/sharepoint-date-column-formatting/)**

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117963/discussion-on-answer-by-mohamed-el-qassas-mvp-json-sharepoint-calculated-columns).

Comment: @melqassas 's answer is the closest we could get. Need to do some data value cleanup, but otherwise this works.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/111315)